# How to get value or create node names in XML like this (<nodeName.variableValue>)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML file like this to work with.

```
    <root>
      <ignore>
        <child>1</child>
      </ignore>
      <select.val>
        <child>2</child>
      </select.val>
    </root>
```

**Scenario 1:**

I want to get the value of the child nodes under *< select.val >*.

I can get them with an xpath like this **/root/select.val/child**. The problem is *< select.val >* might be different for another xml file.. it could be *< select.val2 >* for another xml. If i use a wildcard (**/root/*/child**) it would also get the value under *< ignore >*.

Basically something like this **/root/select.*/child**

**Scenario 2:**

How could i generate an xml file with xslt where I set *val* from a variable/parameter. For example if the value of the variable/parameter is val3 then it would generate a node like this *< select.val3 >*.

Basically something like this.  **< select.< value-of select="$val" > >**

**PS:** Is this possible or should it just use it as an attribute to the node?

Comment: Can your tools support XPath 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, is make use of the **substring** function in your xpath, to check the name of the element matches your criteria

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/*
   [substring(local-name(), 1, 7) = 'select.']/child" />
```

This would only pick **child** elements that were children of elements whose name began with **select.**

It would then be straight-forward to parameterise this to check for name of the element occurring after the full stop

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="root/*
   [substring(local-name(), 1, 7) = 'select.']
   [substring-after(local-name(), '.') = $val]/child" />
```

(Where $val is the parameter containing the name you want to match).

For example, with the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="val" select="'val'" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root/*[substring(local-name(), 1, 7) = 'select.'][substring-after(local-name(), '.') = $val]/child" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<child>2</child>
```

If you wanted to generate a new node, using the parameter in name, you would make use of the **xsl:element** option with attribute value templates (specified by using curly braces) to set the name

```
<xsl:element name="select.{$val}">3</xsl:element>
```

When **$val** is set to 'val3' for example, the following is output

```
<select.val3>3</select.val3>
```

Comment: awesome... it works... using substring was a little longer than expected but i guess it does the trick... do you have any solution for scenario 2? I also need it if i'm going to use this approach...

Comment: very nice. Also answers my possible question